# Why aren't these 4 lines of code working properly given the logical operator precedence in Python tells me they should?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie at Python. This is my code right here. When I do not add parenthesis around `x<=y<=z` it gives me a false bool value in return and the if statement doesn't run.

```
def is_between(x,y,z):
    return x<=y<=z==1

if is_between(1,2,4):
    print('y is between x and z')
```

But if I add the parenthesis, it works perfectly fine. But why is this happening? I checked operator precedence and `<=` has higher precedence than the `==` operator. Shouldn't `x<=y<=z` evaluate first even if I don't add those parentheses?

```
def is_between(x,y,z):
    return (x<=y<=z)==1

if is_between(1,2,4):
    print('y is between x and z')
```

Comment: Also, I don't know who told you that `<=` has higher precedence than `==`, but they're wrong.  [`<=` and `==` have the same precedence, which they share with all the comparison operators.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: I read it at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm

I guess I should have consulted the docs for authentic information.